# Complex Fourier series: which notation is correct?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

In our scripts I found the Professor denoting the complex Fourier series slightly differently

First of the series for a function $f(x) \in V\: $ he defines as:

$\displaystyle f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n\langle e_k,f\rangle\,e_k$ where $e_k = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\,e^{\textstyle i\,k\,x}\quad \text{thus} \quad f =\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\textstyle -i\,k\,x}f(x)\,\mathrm{dx}\,e^{\textstyle i\,k\,x}$

Here I wonder: did he start the sum at $k = 1$ instead of $-\infty$ by mistake or is it safe to say?

Secondly he continues defining:

$ \displaystyle S_n(x) = \sum_{k =-n}^{n} c_k\,e^{\textstyle i\,k\,x}$ where $\displaystyle c_k = \dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\textstyle -i\,k\,x}f(x)\,\mathrm{dx} \quad \text{as well as}$

$\displaystyle \sigma_n(x) = \dfrac{1}{n}\,\left(S_0+ \ldots+ S_{n-1}\right) \quad \text{and conludes}$

$\textbf{Conclusion:}\:\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n = f(x)$

---

What? In my view a Fourier series is to be defined as: $ f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}S_n$

So why all those different notations?

Comment: We need the different notations to express various different concepts. For example, we need $\sigma_n$ as well as $S_n$ because we can _prove_ that $\sigma_n(f)\to f$ (if $f$ is continuous), while it's simply not true that $S_n(f)\tof$ except under stronger hypotheses...

Comment: The first sum should start at $k=-n$.

Comment: alright that's a mistake then but how could $S_n$ and $\sigma_n$ be equal?

Comment: To me $\sigma_n$ looks like $\dfrac{1}{n} S_n$ But that's probably wrong

Comment: $S_n$ and $\sigma_n$ are not equal but have formally the same limit. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation